# Vuejs custom Modal event bus is not firing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, event-bus

I have created my own custom Modal plugin in vuejs to be added to my Laravel 8 app. The problem I am facing is opening the modal.

I have created the plugin in my app.js file

```js
const Modal = {
    install (Vue) {
        this.event = new Vue()

        Vue.prototype.$modal = {
            show (modal, params = {}) {
                Modal.event.$emit('show', modal, params)
            },
            $event: this.event
        }
    }
}

Vue.use(Modal)
```

I have created two vue components for my modal

```html
<!-- AppModal //-->
<template>
    <transition name="modal">
        <div v-if="visible">
            <div class="app-modal" @click.prevent="$modal.hide(name)"></div>
            <div class="app-modal-inner">
                <a href="" @click.prevent="$modal.hide(name)">close</a>
                <slot name="body" :params="params"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "AppModal",
    data () {
        return {
            params: {},
            visible: false,
        }
    },
    props: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setVisible () {
            this.visible = true
        },
        setHidden () {
            this.visible = false
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.$modal.$event.$on('show', (modal, params) => {
            if (this.name !== modal) {
                return
            }

            this.params = params

            this.setVisible()
        })
    },
}
</script>

<!-- AppNonMemberRegisterModal //-->
<template>
    <app-modal name="register">
        <template slot="header">
            <h1 class="text-lg-left text-4xl border border-b-2">Register Now</h1>
        </template>
        <template slot="body" slot-scope="{ params }">
            <p>You need to register in order to share, comment and like on the site</p>
        </template>
    </app-modal>
</template>

<script>
import AppModal from "../AppModal";

export default {
    name: "AppNonMemberRegisterModal",
    components: { AppModal },
}
</script>
```

Where I am firing the event I import the `AppNonMemberRegisterModal` and I have the following click event: `@click.prevent="$modal.show('register')"`.

When the following code is reached `Modal.event.$emit('show', modal, params)` I get the following error messages in my cnosole `console.log(Modal)`

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you have to do `this.event = new Vue()`, try `this.event = Vue` and tell me if you have a new error

Comment: Thanks for your response, by setting ```this.event = Vue``` I get the following TypeError: Modal.event.$emit is not a function

Comment: I just read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) about plugins (as I have never done this before and I don't see any `new Vue()` or similar, and it makes no sense. When you do ` this.$modal.$event.$on` what are you expecting `$event` to be ? The problem is in your `Vue.prototype.$modal` definition, you have defined `show` as a function (that is correct), `$event`, and you are using `$modal.hide` but I don't see it defined in the `prototype`, so that is going to give you errors later because it is not defined.

Comment: Also, are you using Vue 2 or 3 ?

Comment: The hide function is defined but I did not add it here. I am using vue 3

Comment: Okay, for vue 3 it is a little different then, I am not 100% sure if you are using composition API or not, so I have no idea if you are not using it, how can you use your own plugin but this is the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin). I still need to know what did you try doing `$event: this.event`.

Comment: $event: this.event will allow us to listen for events in our AppModel component

Answer (score 1):

Vue 3 removes the Event API (i.e., `$on`, `$off`, etc.). The [migration guide recommends using `tiny-emitter` to create your own event bus](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus). That example shows how to create a global bus, but it seems your plugin just needs a local bus, which you could create like this:

```js
// eventBus.js
import Emitter from 'tiny-emitter'

export function createEventBus() {
  const emitter = new Emitter()
  return {
    $on: (...args) => emitter.on(...args),
    $once: (...args) => emitter.once(...args),
    $off: (...args) => emitter.off(...args),
    $emit: (...args) => emitter.emit(...args)
  }
}
```

Then in your plugin, [create a global with `app.config.globalProperties`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties), referring to the locally created event bus:

```js
// myPlugin.js
import { createEventBus } from './eventBus'

export default {
  install(app) {
    const eventBus = createEventBus()

    app.config.globalProperties.$modal = {
      show (modal, params = {}) {
        eventBus.$emit('show', modal, params)
      },
      $event: eventBus
    }
  }
}
```

And install it:

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import myPlugin from './myPlugin'

createApp(App).use(myPlugin).mount('#app')
```

Also be aware that your slot usage in `AppRegisterModal.vue` needs to be updated to the latest syntax ([`v-slot`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-slot) or `#` shorthand):

```html
<app-modal name="register">
  <!--
  <template slot="header">
  -->
  <template #header>

  <!--
  <template slot="body" slot-scope="{ params }">
  -->
  <template #body="{ params }">
</app-modal>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-modal-plugin-az8atz?file=src%2FmyPlugin.js)